# React Parent Child component not working

Tags: reactjs, components

I am trying to access information from a parent component in React but keep getting an error. React doesn't seem to understand imageUrl and username is part of another component. Please help!

Here is my code:

```js
var USER_DATA = {
 name: 'Ayaz Uddin',
 username: 'ayaz2589',
 image: 'https://scontent-lga3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/1511676_10152124607269164_1288963176_n.jpg?oh=d725f8677a8369269e2ea65ffe9a3a63&oe=582CDD2C'
}

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var ProfilePic = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return <img src={this.props.imageUrl} style={{ height: 100, width: 100}} />
 }
});

var ProfileLink = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>
    <a href={'http://www.github.com/' + this.props.username}>
     {this.props.username}
    </a>
   </div>
  )
 }
});

var ProfileName = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>{this.props.name}</div>
  )
 }
});

var Avatar = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  return (
   <div>
    <profilePic imageUrl={this.props.user.image} />
    <profileName name={this.props.user.name} />
    <profileLink username={this.props.user.username} />
   </div>
  )
 }
})

ReactDOM.render(
 <Avatar user={USER_DATA} />, 
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and here is the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lnew.png)

Comment: There is difference in the class names; u r calling profilePic but class defined is ProfilePic, is that a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<profilePic imageUrl={this.props.user.image} />
<profileName name={this.props.user.name} />
<profileLink username={this.props.user.username} />
```

To:

```
<ProfilePic imageUrl={this.props.user.image} />
<ProfileName name={this.props.user.name} />
<ProfileLink username={this.props.user.username} />
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/27x15mgw/1/) with changes made.